# How to add controls dynamically in WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Am new to MVVM Design Pattern as well as coding and I now want to create dynamic buttons (eg: Country Names) from an SQL Database which has to be inserted from different Forms.

I have created a grid with 3 column.  What I want is that when a new country will be added, new buttons to be created with content as country name. After 3rd column new row has to be created in the grid.

Also when I click on that button the corresponding data to be displayed from database.  For this I have used a click event handler for all buttons.

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), thanks, begging for help and your name should never be part of a good post (your name is already in your profile). It is not impolite to leave that out but it is wasting readers time when you put it in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I didn't get your question right, but here's my guess and advice.
`Grid` is not very suitable for MVVM scenarios.
You can have some sort of collection holding countries, where each collection item represents country name. This is your ViewModel. Now in your View you can define some sort of an `ItemsControl`, e.g. `ListBox`. For this control, you should define ItemTemplate containig `Button` that binds its `Content` property to Country Name, and its Command property to a command on Country object allowing it to be deleted from database.

Comment: Grid is good for giving some basic layout, but if you want to add items, you need something that has an itemssource.

Comment: I understand that. The problem, to my opinion, is that the author has some collection which he wants to bind to a control. But he wants a specific control, something like UniformGrid 3x3 or WrapPanel that wraps after each 3rd element. But these panels are not ItemControls. I can suggest binding collection to ItemsControl and override ItemControl's layout panel to be UniformGrid, for e.g.

Comment: I have no issue with Grid or WrapPanel.I have a country table with details like (Name,Flag,Currency etc.).The question is when a new data will be added in database a button with content as country name has to be added at the same time.While clicking on that button details of that country has to be display.